# Is /tmp/crontab.NKQ7JX/crontab expcted as a cron job?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

My apologies for asking... This looks very unusual to me, but I'm not a cron expert because I rarely have to do anything with it. I'm trying to setup a `cron` job to run once every 15 minutes.

```
$ echo $EDITOR
emacs
$ sudo crontab -e
```

When I run the command, it brings up the wrong editor (GNU nano) with an unexpected filename. However, it has the expected comments:

[image]

The text that can't be seen is:

```
# Run ci20-rng.exe to replenish /dev/random once every 15 minutes
*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/ci20-rng.exe
```

Is the wrong editor and an incorrect filename expected? It seems like putting long term jobs in a temp directory seems kind of dicey, especially if its world readable/writable. I guess more importantly, will the job run every 15 minutes?

Comment: I am not used to Debian (I used Slackware and FreeBSD), but on a general guess: 

1) What is your visual editor set to? (`echo VISUAL`). I is nano?  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference for the difference.

2) Saving a temporarily working copy in /tmp seems fair. The end result should be sanity checked and then copied to its normal place.

Comment: @Hennes - According to [Debian's EnvironmentVariables wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables), there is an `EDITOR` but no `VISUAL`. [Ubuntu's wiki adds `VISUAL`](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), but Debian's wiki lacks it.

Comment: Ah. that is the downsite of different distributions. Always tiny differences. One more guess. You sudo, thus you do not use your own enviroment. What is roots EDITOR set to?

Comment: Done. I should have considered sudo earlier. There are so many questions here and on linux&unix where things do not work as expected with other settings or with redirects. Still, answer found. And your `sudo -E crontab -e` is brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editor part:**

```
$ echo $EDITOR
emacs
```

Shows your personal editor setting.

You then do a `sudo crontab -e` which changes the user to root and uses root's environment, which can have different settings including a different setting for EDITOR.

**/tmp part**

Many programs do not edit a file in place. That make a local copy (e.g. in /tmp/) and you edit that. On save and quit a sanity check if performed before the result is copied back to its original place. Having nano show that it is working on the copy in /tmp/ is not bad. So you don`t have to worry about it.